# Delete a firestore document without knowing the collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know the document Id, but i don't know the collection Id. I can find the document using a collectionGroup query, but is there a similar way to delete it?

To be more exact I have posts, that have comments. For architectural reasons I want to be able to delete a comment without knowing the post Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a document, you be able to build a full unique path to it.  In API terms, that is called a DocumentReference.  If you don't know the collection name, then you can't build a reference to it, therefore you can't delete it.  If your only way of identifying a document is by a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), then that's what you'll have to do.